# Java pass-by-reference-by-value issue, Map in map in map in map

Tags: java, hashmap

This is the representation of the data that I want in Java.

e.g. country --> league --> season --> team with initial rating of 0

- Eng

  - PRL

    - 2013/14

      - Arsenal  0
      - Manches. 0
    - 2014/15

      - Arsenal  0
      - Manches. 0
  - CHA

    - 2013/14
- Ger

  - BUN

    - 2013/14

      - BayernM  0

But the problem is that, the values seems to getting override by the pass by reference by value of Java.

Therefore I obtain, always one result in the map and not a kind of list.

Here you will see my implementation of the object Season.

```
public class Season {

    private HashMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Double>>>> mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams;

    public Season() {
        this.mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Double>>>>();
    }

    public void collectSeasons(String country, String league, String season,
            String team) {
        Map<String, Map<String, Double>> seasonTeam = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Double>>();
        Map<String, Double> teamRating = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Double>>> leagueSeason = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, Double>>>();


// check if the the country already exist otherwise create new
        if (mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.containsKey(country)) {


// check if the league already exists if that country exists
            if (mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.get(country).containsValue(league)) {



// check if the season exists if we know we have a valide country and league
                if (mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.get(country).get(league)
                        .containsKey(season)) {


// check if that team exists in the season of that league in that country
// if it exists, do nothing otherwise put it in
                    if (mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.get(country).get(league)
                            .get(season).containsKey(team)) {

                    } else {
                        teamRating.put(team, 0.0);
                        mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.get(country).get(league)
                                .put(season, teamRating);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                teamRating.put(team, 0.0);
                seasonTeam.put(season, teamRating);
                mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.get(country).put(league, seasonTeam);
            }
        } else {
            teamRating.put(team, 0.0);
            seasonTeam.put(season, teamRating);
            leagueSeason.put(league, seasonTeam);
            mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.put(country, leagueSeason);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Encapsulation is your friend.

Comment: Maintenance of this code is a nightmare to me :(

Comment: I would change the design to at least have my own classes that contain `Map`s to store the data and then relate these classes rather than using plain `Map<String, Map` over and over.

Comment: I have a small suggestion for you... Don't use Strings as keys to nested Maps. and... Don't nest maps if you can help it.

Comment: This is one of the few Java questions where I feel like Maps are not the answer, but the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a solution. The problem was that it overwrites existing maps.
With other words, I had to check if it already existed

### Solution

```
public void collectSeasons(String country, String league, String season,
            String team) {

        try {           
            if(!mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.get(country).get(league).get(season).containsKey(team)){
                mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.get(country).get(league).get(season).put(team, 0.0);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        if (mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.containsKey(country)) {
            if (mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.get(country).containsKey(league)) {
                Map<String,Double> teamRating = new HashMap<String,Double>();
                Map<String, Map<String, Double>> seasonTeam = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Double>>();

                teamRating.put(team, 0.0);
                seasonTeam.put(season, teamRating);
                mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.get(country).get(league).put(season, teamRating);

            } else {
                Map<String,Double> teamRating = new HashMap<String,Double>();
                Map<String, Map<String, Double>> seasonTeam = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Double>>();

                teamRating.put(team, 0.0);
                seasonTeam.put(season, teamRating);
                mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.get(country).put(league, seasonTeam);
            }
        } else {
            Map<String,Double> teamRating = new HashMap<String,Double>();
            Map<String, Map<String, Double>> seasonTeam = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Double>>();
            Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Double>>> leagueSeason = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, Double>>>();

            teamRating.put(team, 0.0);
            seasonTeam.put(season, teamRating);
            leagueSeason.put(league, seasonTeam);
            mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.put(country, leagueSeason);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thus, I've used a try catch. With other words, It "JUST TRY"  to add a new team into the nested hashmaps.

If this fails. Check which hashmap doesn't exist 'yet'. And if you've found it, create the needed hashmaps and add them

### why

with :

```
mapSeasonsLeaguesAndTeams.get(country).get(league).get(season).get(team)
```

I get the needed results + it is flexible.